# Why is Proxy being called for nested elements?

Tags: javascript, typescript, cypress, javascript-proxy

I'm attempting to abstract some Cypress methods into a helper object using getters.

The intended behavior is that I can do something like this:

```
todoApp.todoPage.todoApp.main.rows.row
    .first().should('have.text', 'Pay electric bill');
todoApp.todoPage.todoApp.main.rows.row
    .last().should('have.text', 'Walk the dog');
```

and it should simply return a nested property, UNLESS said property comes from Cypress, in which case it should call cy.get on the selector, and then get the property from that object. Behavior should be effectively identical to:

```
cy.get('[data-test=todo_app] [data-test=todo_page] [data-test=todo_app] [data-test=main] [data-test=rows] [data-test=row]')
    .first().should('have.text', 'Pay electric bill');
cy.get('[data-test=todo_app] [data-test=todo_page] [data-test=todo_app] [data-test=main] [data-test=rows] [data-test=row]')
    .last().should('have.text', 'Walk the dog');
```

Unfortunately, this isn't quite working as expected. If I log the property being retrieved, I see `specWindow` and `chainerId` as property... even though I never used those properties! You can see this in the log, as the get command is repeated.

This does not work as expected:

```
// filled algorithmically in the real code, but to keep the sample simple, hardcoded here
const cypressChainableMethodsAndProperties = ['first', 'last', 'within', 'should', 'specWindow', 'chainerId'];

// roughly: used with Object.defineProperties(proxifiedGet(selector), {...}) to generate at runtime
function proxifiedGet(selector: string) {
    return new Proxy(
        new Object(),
        {
            get: function (target, property) {
                const propertyStr = property.toString();

                if (cypressChainableMethodsAndProperties.includes(propertyStr)) {
                    return cy.get(selector)[property];
                }
                return target[property as keyof typeof target];
            },
        });
}

todoApp.todoPage.todoApp.main.rows.row
    .first().should('have.text', 'Pay electric bill');
todoApp.todoPage.todoApp.main.rows.row
    .last().should('have.text', 'Walk the dog');
```

[image]

But this works... except for the extra `.get` being undesirable:

```
function proxifiedGet(selector: string) {
    return new Proxy(
        new Object(),
        {
            get: function (target, property) {
                const propertyStr = property.toString();

                if (propertyStr === 'get' ) {
                    return cy.get(selector);
                }
                return target[property as keyof typeof target];
            },
        });
}

todoApp.todoPage.todoApp.main.rows.row.get
    .first().should('have.text', 'Pay electric bill');
todoApp.todoPage.todoApp.main.rows.row.get
    .last().should('have.text', 'Walk the dog');
```

[image]

Here's a minimal test case:

```
describe('example', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.visit('https://www.cypress.io/');
    });

    it('foo', () => {
        proxifiedGet('[data-cy="header-login"]')
            .first().should('have.text', 'Log In ');
    });
);
```

Comment: Why are you using a proxy around `new Object()` instead of one around the cypress object?

Comment: because you can't use Cypress commands before tests start executing ☹️ not to mention calling cy.get in bulk could have consequences

Comment: But you're creating the proxy only during the test, are you not? This question isn't really answerable until you provide the complete code for a [mcve]

Comment: Given cypress needs to visit a web page in order to run, that's not super doable without posting dozens of lines of code. But you should be able to plug that into any local tests - `proxifiedGet('[data-test=foo]').first().should('have.text', 'something')` should do it. Or any selector. So I guess I could pick a random webpage on the net.

Comment: And no, I'm creating the proxy prior to the test, in another file

Comment: "*posting dozens of lines of code*" - yes, please do that, instead of posting screenshots!

Comment: "*I'm creating the proxy prior to the test, in another file*" - don't do that then. Put the code that creates the proxy in a function, call it during the test.

Comment: I've provided a minimal test case at the end of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I see `specWindow` and `chainerId` as property... even though I never used those properties!

It's not your code that's using them, but probably the `.first()` method which you are invoking on your proxy - i.e. `this` inside the Cypress method code is your proxy. But your proxy is not a Cypress instance, and not even a proxy around one.

A hacky workaround would be to bind the returned method to the `cy.get(selector)` on which you accessed the method, but this whole design with the `cypressChainableMethodsAndProperties` heuristic doesn't look right.

Instead, create a proxy around the respective Cypress object that is chained from `cy`:

```
function proxifiedFind(chain) {
    return new Proxy(chain, {
        get: function (target, key) {
            if (key in target) {
                return target[key];
            }
            return proxifiedFind(chain.find(`[data-test=${key}]`));
        }
    });
}
function proxifiedGet(selector: string) {
    return proxifiedFind(cy.get(selector));
}
```

Comment: Your comment about `this` appears to be correct; binding it to the get function call seemed to solve the issue. Far as the rest of that, that sort of chainable design is what `chai` uses, which is part of Cypress. I didn't like it at first, either, but I got used to it.